# Problem when displaying article in blade, solutions?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Good afternoon,

I created a cms with laravel, to show the content of the blog I use

```
{!!$post->content!!}
```

So far everything is fine, but my post is about programming and sometimes I need to show a function like for example

[image]

the problem comes when wanting to show this function as simple information of my article, and it is that blade obviously tries to execute that function because it is inside {!! !!} ...

Can someone come up with a solution to this problem? Thank you...

----------------------SOLUTION-----------------------------------

Finally I found the problem, Blade was not interpreting the function as he thought, it was vuejs. I solve it by removing the contents of the label that I have defined for the time. Thanks for your comments

Comment: What you want is to display a function on your blade? Something like this `<h1>myName()</h1>`

Comment: Blade won't execute PHP functions within a template tag. *HTML* within it will be interpreted, though. Can you give us an example of what `$post->content` would contain that causes this?

Comment: @ChristianGallarmin Exact! is a bit complicated to explain maybe, to have that function within the content of my post, and show post {!! !!}, blade tries to execute it

Comment: @ceejayoz 
Yes, through travem tinymce I write this: <pre class = "language-markup"> <code> {{myName ()}} </ code> </ pre> but to be inside {!! !}} try to execute the function

Comment: I tried to [duplicate what you're claiming](https://gist.github.com/ceejayoz/0258a410b061ca333f4f353179a33292) with no luck. The function is not executed and I see `{{ date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}` raw output as I'd expect. Something else is going on.

Comment: Incidentally, `{!! '{{ $foo }}' !!}` produces a different result - the `{{ }}` are interpreted, but the resulting PHP still isn't executed.

Comment: @ceejayoz 
It's super weird, I've done what you say and to me if I execute the function you've written!

Answer (score 1):

return the `{{` characters as `@{{` at rendering through Balde. Blade will ignore those brackets.

Make a helper with str_replace.